# Update product stock quantity and status in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, stock

I'm trying to have the product's stock quantity set to zero when there is an specific post_meta

I'm hooking into 'woocommerce_update_product' . When I click "update", this starts, and does update correctly; however, the action never finishes. ( the page is just loading ... )

When I refresh the page and check the stock, this is modified correctly.

Am I doing anything wrong?

This is my code

```
add_action('woocommerce_update_product', 'sv_set_no_stock_when_discontinued', 10, 1);
function sv_set_no_stock_when_discontinued($prodId){

    $discontinued = get_post_meta($prodId, '_is_discontinued', true);

    if($discontinued == 'yes'){

        $product = wc_get_product($prodId);

        // Using WC setters
        $product->set_manage_stock(true);
        $product->set_stock_quantity(0);
        $product->set_stock_status('outofstock');

        // Save Product
        $product->save();
    }
}
```

After leaving it for a while, i get the following errors:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1077936128 bytes exhausted (tried
> to allocate 20480 bytes) in \wp-includes\meta.php on line 1078
>
> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 1077936128 bytes exhausted (tried
> to allocate 20480 bytes) in
> \wp-includes\class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php on line 72

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The WC_Product Object is already included as 2nd argument for `woocommerce_update_product` Hook… So you can change a little bit your code like:

**But** as this hook is located on `WC_Product_Data_Store_CPT` Class, **It doesn't really like the `WC_Product` setter methods and especially `save()` method.**

So instead we will replace this hook with the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'set_no_stock_if_discontinued' );
function set_no_stock_if_discontinued( $product ) {
    if( $product->get_meta('_is_discontinued') === 'yes' 
    || ( isset($_POST['_is_discontinued']) 
    && esc_attr($_POST['_is_discontinued']) === 'yes' ) ) {

        // Using WC setters
        $product->set_manage_stock(true);
        $product->set_stock_quantity(0);
        $product->set_stock_status('outofstock');
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **Note:** The `save()` method **is not needed** as it's triggered just after this hook.

> **Global note:** You can also set "manage stock" to false.

Comment: Just tested it, and it works great. Do you know why the save() method wouldn't work in the 'woocommerce_update_product' hook?

Comment: @Jpv Look at the code [where your hook is located](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.6.1/includes/data-stores/class-wc-product-data-store-cpt.php#L269) and you will maybe understand…